# Ordering a barchart in R with list as a datasource

Tags: r, csv, bar-chart

I'm trying to order a barchart in R but I'm getting funny results. The data source is a list. Maybe this is the problem, but I don't know how to sort it out.

The initial chart is as follows:
[image: BarChart1]

I get it with the following code:

```
file <- c("C://path//file.csv")
dataSource <- read.table(file, header=T, sep=",")
#typeof(dataSource) ==> this gives me a 'list'
dataChart <- dataSource[ , c("Product","YTD")]
dataChart <- na.omit(dataChart)
barplot(dataChart[ ,2], names.arg = dataChart[ ,1],
      horiz = TRUE,
      ylab = "",
      xlab = "",
      main="Title", 
      las=1)
```

If I add the following to sort the chart:

```
dataChart <- as.data.frame(dataChart)[order("YTD"),]
```

I get the following:

[image: BarChart2]

The data source is as follows:

```
dataSource = structure(list(Product = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("ADT", "BHL", 
"CEX", "CMX", "CTL", "HTH", "MTL", "SSL", "TLS", "UTV", "WEX", 
"WLD", "WMX"), class = "factor"), YTD = c(67L, 5026L, 503L, 29L, 
3975L, 876L, NA, 40L, 62L, 1395L, 717L, NA, 423L, 277L, 35L)), .Names = c("Product", 
"YTD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Any ideas on how to get the chart sorted correctly? Is the problem how the data is loaded?

Comment: structure(list(Product = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("ADT", "BHL", 
"CEX", "CMX", "CTL", "HTH", "MTL", "SSL", "TLS", "UTV", "WEX", 
"WLD", "WMX"), class = "factor"), YTD = c(67L, 5026L, 503L, 29L, 
3975L, 876L, NA, 40L, 62L, 1395L, 717L, NA, 423L, 277L, 35L)), .Names = c("Product", 
"YTD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just want to sort the data.

```
dataChart = dataChart[order(dataChart$YTD),]
barplot(dataChart[ ,2], names.arg = dataChart[ ,1],
      horiz = TRUE,
      ylab = "",
      xlab = "",
      main="Title", 
      las=1)
```

[image: sorted barplot]

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks G5W